# How to use Google Cloud SDK in local environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I am currently using Google's 'legacy standalone SDK' for management of my google app engine python projects.  This provides a nice GUI where I can select and run a project locally and then deploy it when I'm happy with testing.

I recently received the following message from Google '... App Engine app that has used the legacy standalone SDK in the past 30 days, and need to be migrated to Cloud SDK' so I installed the Cloud SDK.

The provided Google Cloud SDK Shell a) runs as a dos window, and b) appears to duplicate the on-line (live) Dashboard.  Given that I can't change (local) code and deploy without testing, my questions are:-
1) how do I run a project locally?
2) how do I view local logs?
3) when happy, how do I deploy?
or... is there GUI for the Local Environment?
or... is the above documented somewhere that I have not found?

Many thanks and apologies if this is a dumb question.
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On July 30, 2019, the [standalone App Engine SDK is deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sdk-gcloud-migration). Here you can check documentation how to [migrate from AppCft to gcloud command line](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrating-from-appcfg-to-gcloud)

1. How to test your application locally?

   [For Python you can use Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) that includes Cloud Datastore Emulator. (There is also solution for Java [Java 8 Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server)).
2. How to view logs locally?

   In python to [debug your code from the command line use interactive console](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_the_interactive_console). You have to import to your code [PDB debbuger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)
3. How to deploy application?

   You [deploy your app with gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app) `gcloud app deploy`. Cloud SDK does not include GUI for deployment.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Czuczwara, you're a lifesaver.